# Windows batch: analogue of *nix shell read

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for analogue of Unix/Linux shell command `read`. Now I use variables set via `set password="bigsecret"` and `%password%` but I want use via command prompt.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /p password="Please enter your password: "
echo you entered %password%.
```

Comment: Yes, your true. I was looking for help via `help` in cmd. Ehh... Windows world...